# Create new list by taking first item from first list, and last item from second list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I loop through my 2 lists so that I can use

```
a=[1,2,3,8,12]
b=[2,6,4,5,6]
```

to get

```
[1,6,2,5,3,8,6,12,2]
```

OR use

```
d=[a,b,c,d]
e=[w,x,y,z]
```

to get

```
[a,z,b,y,c,x,d,w]
```

(1st element from 1st list, last element from 2nd list)
(2nd element from 1st list, 2nd to last element from 2nd list)

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[value for pair in zip(a, b[::-1]) for value in pair]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can zip the first list with the reverse of second one (using `itertools.izip_longest`) then join the columns using `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> d=['a','b','c','d']
>>> e=['w','x','y','z']
>>> 
>>> from itertools import chain, zip_longest # in python 2 use izip_longest
>>> 
>>> list(chain(*izip_longest(d, e[::-1])))
['a', 'z', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'x', 'd', 'w']
```

The advantage of using `zip_longest()` is that it takes a `fillvalue` argument which will be passed to fill the omitted items when the length of your lists are not equal.

If you are sure that the length of the lists are equal you better to use built-in function `zip()`.

```
>>> d=['a','b']
>>> e=['w','x','y','z']
>>> list(chain(*izip_longest(d, e[::-1], fillvalue='')))
['a', 'z', 'b', 'y', '', 'x', '', 'w']
```

More pythonic way suggested by @Jon Clements:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(d, reversed(e))))
```

Comment: It's considered better form to use `chain.from_iterable(iterable)` instead of `chain(*iterable)`... and if you wanted to avoid creating a new list, instead of `e[::-1]` you can use `reversed(e)` so all in all: `list(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(d, reversed(e))))`

Comment: Perhaps the method I'd use though is to take the `roundrobin` itertools recipe, and provide it `d` and `reversed(e)` as inputs - that'll handle nicely varying length lists (without worrying about fillvalues) and will scale to an arbitrary number of iterables as input

Comment: @JonClements Yes, using `reverse()` is a better idea but I thinks using `roundrobin` (although is the pythonic way) is overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have made some tests for python2:

```
import time
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain, izip_longest

a = [1, 2, 3, 8, 12]
b = [2, 6, 4, 5, 6]

print "Using value and zip"
starttime = time.time()
c = [value for pair in zip(a, b[::-1]) for value in pair]
elapsed = time.time() - starttime
print c
print elapsed

print "Using chain and izip"
starttime = time.time()
c = list(chain(*izip_longest(a, b[::-1])))
elapsed = time.time() - starttime
print c
print elapsed

print "Using itemgetter"
c = []
starttime = time.time()
for i in xrange(0, len(a)):
    c.append(itemgetter(i)(a))
    c.append(itemgetter(len(b)-i-1)(b))
elapsed = time.time() - starttime
print c
print elapsed
```

output:

```
Using value and zip
[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 2]
1.59740447998e-05
Using chain and izip
[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 2]
3.2901763916e-05
Using itemgetter
[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 2]
1.4066696167e-05
```

Sometimes the first method is faster and sometimes the third.

Those are the results for lists lenght = 1000:

```
Using value and zip
0.000767946243286
Using chain and izip
0.000431060791016
Using itemgetter
0.00203609466553
```

As You can see the second method gets better for longer lists.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
a=[1,2,3,8,12]
b=[2,6,4,5,6]
>>> a1 = list(map(lambda x: a1.extend([x,0]), a))
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> a1
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 8, 0, 12, 0]
>>> b1 = list(map(lambda x: b1.extend([0,x]), b[::-1]))
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> b1
[0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 2]
>>> c = [x+y for x,y in zip(a1,b1)]
>>> c
[1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4, 8, 6, 12, 2]
```

If a and b are with different lengths, then:

```
>>> c = [x+y for x,y in izip_longest(a1,b1)] #you choose your fillvalue.
```